# Hadoop streaming with Bash - how slow?

Tags: python, bash, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have heard from several articles that Hadoop streaming with bash is significantly slower than a compiled code or python. Is this only true for sort commands and the like? My script needs to

-copy file to node 
-on node execute a commercial program with file as argument
-pass output back to folder

My intuition is telling me that this should be a similar speed to the compiled versions. Would it be?

Answer (score 2):

The main idea why Hadoop Streaming is considered to be slow is that for both mapper and reducer you have to pass arguments via stdin, which means you have to serialize them as a text, and to get the output of both mapper and reducer you have to deserialize them from the text back to Java structures, which usually consumes much time.

If you have a third party compiled application that is capable of reading the input data from stdin and passing data to stdout you don't have much choice but to run it in Hadoop Streaming or in Spark pipe. But of course the native mapreduce application application would be faster as it would eliminate the need for data serialization/deserialization on passing it to the application

But if your application just accepts the filename and reads the file by itself (from NFS, for instance), it would be the same speed as a native one, but of course you should consider that this type of use is not the case neither for Hadoop nor for Spark - these frameworks were developed to process the data with APIs they provide

Comment: Can't upvote due to rep, but thank you for your response! This makes a lot of sense to me. I know this isn't the type of job hadoop was meant to handle, but I need a platform to enable parallel computing on google cloud, and hadoop seemed like the best choice.

Comment: If your case is passing file names to the compiled application, you can try to make your own inputformat, which would give you a separate input split for each file name, this way each of the tasks to process a single file would be scheduled separately and restarted on failure